# Angular display categories and subCategories in ul or table

Tags: angular, categories

I need to display my **categories** in ***ul*** or ***table*** and on ***click*** on the **category** I need to show ***subcategories***, but I don't have idea how I can do that. ;(

```
<ul>
  <li>category name</li>
</ul>
```

I need to do that from an object.

```
  cats = [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "parent_id": 'root',
      "category": "Dress"
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "parent_id": "1",
      "category": "Dress 2"
    },


    {
      "id": "19",
      "parent_id": "1",
      "category": "Men"
    },
    {
      "id": "30",
      "parent_id": "19",
      "category": "Shorts 2"
    },
    {
      "id": "31",
      "parent_id": "19",
      "category": "Shorts"
    }
  ]
```

So I need to change ul or table structure every time when user click on category or subcategory name.

The Root category is a first display category.

if it helps i use ngx-datatables on my the project. But I can use default tables. I just need to understand the logic

Thank You!

Comment: the solution is here ----------------> https://stackoverflow.com/a/65069638/14733261

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a list(eg: filteredList) to store the data to be shown. Change the data of the filteredList according to the category selected.

```
filteredList = [];

ngOnInit(){
this.filterByCategory('root')
}

filterByCategory(categoryId){
    this.filteredList = this.cats.filter(cat => cat.parent_id == categoryId)
}
```

Here the filter function will return an array of elements which will satisfy the condition ("cat.parent_id == categoryId")

Now update the template to reflect the changes

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="bootstrap table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Category Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let cat of filteredList">
        <td>
        <a (click)="filterByCategory(cat.id)">{{ cat.category }}</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65069638/14733261

Answer (score 0):

Use [`*ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) to iterate array.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let cat of cats">{{cat.category}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yep. but also I need a tag for display categories where parent category is clicked category. here is a my problem)

Comment: can you update your question in detail what you want exactly?

Comment: ok. onInit I need to display categories that have parentId root. then on click this categories I need to display categories where parentId is 1
cats = [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "parent_id": 'root',
      "category": "Dress"
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "parent_id": "1",
      "category": "Dress 2"
    },


    {
      "id": "19",
      "parent_id": "1",
      "category": "Men"
    },
    {
      "id": "30",
      "parent_id": "19",
      "category": "Shorts 2"
    },
    {
      "id": "31",
      "parent_id": "19",
      "category": "Shorts"
    }
  ]