# Angular Display Categories & Subcategories in table

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to display my categories and subcategories in the table.

So I have object with categories

```
  cats = [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "parent_id": 'root',
      "category": "Dress"
    },
    {
      "id": "17",
      "parent_id": "1",
      "category": "Dress 2"
    },


    {
      "id": "19",
      "parent_id": "1",
      "category": "Men"
    },
    {
      "id": "30",
      "parent_id": "19",
      "category": "Shorts 2"
    },
    {
      "id": "31",
      "parent_id": "19",
      "category": "Shorts"
    }
  ]
```

OnInit I need to display categories where **parent_id** is *root*

And on click for example on **Dress** category
I need to show **child categories** (where **parent_id is 1**)

This is a table

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="bootstrap table-striped">
      <tr>
        <th>Category Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor="let cat of cats">
        <td>
          <a>{{ cat.category }}</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I need to use? maybe some filter? I don't have idea and I didn't find anything

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list(eg: filteredList) to store the data to be shown.
Change the data of the filteredList according to the category selected.

```
filteredList = [];

ngOnInit(){
this.filterByCategory('root')
}

filterByCategory(categoryId){
    this.filteredList = this.cats.filter(cat => cat.parent_id == categoryId)
}
```

Here the filter function will return an array of elements which will satisfy the condition ("cat.parent_id == categoryId")

Now update the template to reflect the changes

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <table class="bootstrap table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Category Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let cat of filteredList">
        <td>
        <a (click)="filterByCategory(cat.id)">{{ cat.category }}</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```